# VueJs auh0 social authentication, how to customize handle redicrect

Tags: vue.js, auth0

Using VueJs SDK .

My redirect url is example.com/callback, inside routes I have callback component which suppose to send user data to backend and check if user exists and log user in otherwise create new user and get back jwt from our backend application .

Problem is following, inside created/mounted cycle I can not reach auth0Client and so user properties.

`this.$auth.auth0Client`

I have to do this hack

```js
const interval = setInterval(async () => {
    count++;
    if (this.$auth.auth0Client) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        let loggedUser = await this.$auth.auth0Client.getUser();
        if(loggedUser) {
          const email = loggedUser.email;
          const name = loggedUser.name;
          try {
              //backend logic
          } catch(e) {
              console.log(e)
          }
        }
    } else {
        if (count > 80) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
      }
}, 100)
```

My problem/question is how to handle this better as it seems not very logical and nice.
I want to send authenticated user data to our backend and do the rest there,

Auth0 seems to lack the details for this type of usecases

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solve my own problem by using Vue event system

```
this.auth0Client = await createAuth0Client({
    domain: options.domain,
    client_id: options.clientId,
    audience: options.audience,
    redirect_uri: redirectUri,
    responseType: 'token'
  });
  this.$eventBus.$emit('auth0Client',this.auth0Client) // creating event here after auth0Client
```

handling it in callback component

```
 this.$eventBus.$on('auth0Client', async (auth0Client) => { 
  //logic here
 })
```

Do not forget to register your event bus in main js

```
 Vue.prototype.$eventBus = new Vue();
```

Hope it will help